# From getSupportFragmentManager to getFragmentManager

Tags: android, xml

My app has two fragments with cardviews, if clicked on 1st fragment on a card, it will fetch the 2nd fragment and three buttons are above RecyclerView in each fragment.

Fragment was overlapped, so I give background color to stop (I know its a wrong process). And also used

```
container.removeAllViews();
```

In genymotion (4.4.4) the buttons are showing but in real device its showing the old buttons.

The problem is I am using two different FragmentManagers, one is getFragmentManager and the other is getSupportFragmentManager which is creating problem.

So I need to change the getSupportFragmentManager to getFragmentManager.

Can you help ???

```
AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
GroupAnswerSummary fragment = new GroupAnswerSummary();

//android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager =((Activity)mContexts).getFragmentManager();
((Activity)mContexts).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    //appCompatActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerQ, fragment).addToBackStack(GroupAnswerSummary.class.getName()).commit();
```

XML is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/containerQ">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_insert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Ask"
        android:textSize="12sp" />



    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:progressDrawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_i_asked"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
        android:text="I Asked"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_temp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
        android:text="temp"
        android:textSize="12sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Import :

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;


import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Comment: "The problem is I am using two different FragmentManagers" – Why? All of your `Fragment`-related classes should be imported from the support library. Why are you mixing support `Fragment`s and native `Fragment`s?

Comment: No, I don't want to use. Can you please suggest the proper method with code.

Comment: My suggestion is to use only support `Fragment`s. Is there some reason you're not?

Comment: I am using it within RecyclerView.Adapter

Comment: Why is that preventing you from using support `Fragment`s?

Comment: I am getting an error here .replace(R.id.containerQ, fragment). Wrong 2nd argument, required android.app.fragment

Comment: You need the support `FragmentManager` there. The simplest thing to do would be `((FragmentActivity)mContexts).getSupportFragmentManager()`, but you really shouldn't be doing `FragmentTransaction`s inside your `Adapter` anyway. You should be calling back to the `Activity` somehow – e.g., via `interface` – and have it do the `FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. One more thing I didn't understand why it was working in Genymotion but not in real device???

Comment: Unknown. There's really not enough information for me to even hazard a guess.